# error while running a sql*plus script

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, shell, sqlplus

i have a script which simply connect to the table in sql*plus and inserts a row in the table.

it is throwing an error as below:

```
SP2-0552: Bind variable "BIND" not declared
```

i am not able to figure out exactly what the bind variable is in the query that it is trying to insert.

Comment: Showing us the script might help us figure out the problem more easily

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to run a sql like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE :BIND = 1;
```

SQL*Plus identifies `:BIND` as a bind variable, but you haven't declared one in your session yet. To declare the bind variable use the `VAR(IABLE)` command.

```
VAR BIND NUMBER
```

Then, you can assign a value to the variable.

```
EXEC :BIND := 1
```

Run the `select` again to confirm that the bind variable is now set. Note that you can also use this variable to hold results from single-row queries.

```
SELECT 1 INTO :BIND FROM DUAL;
```